# How can I check if the authentication is still valid and redirect after?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Like the title says. I check the authentication using a request to the API. If the requests returns false, I want to log the user out. However if I do this with a guard, it doesn't work because it runs synchronously and I can't wait for the request to show the page each time I go to another page.

Example:

```
  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    this.authService.checkAuth(); // Sends request to backend for auth validation
    return this.authService.getIsAuthenticated(); // Shows/doesn't show page before validation
  }
```

If I run it async, it would wait every time for the response before it shows the page. I want it to show the page during the request, but if the request returns false, I want to logout `ie this.authService.logout()`.

Can I achieve this without putting it in the `IonicViewDidLoad` of every page?

The scenario:

> A user is logged in on two devices. The user unlinks one of the
>   devices. So during the session, the other device needs to be logged
>   out.
>
> Possibly immediately. But I suspect this would require an interval to
>   continueously check if the device is still logged in. Therefore it
>   would suffice to do this on change of a page (like in the guard).

Comment: Look to interceptor. It informed you if customer is logged out on request to server.

Comment: The interceptor intercepts every request. If I make a request to check the login within the interceptor, it would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: You should check the request. If it is login request then don't  handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use jwt token to authorization handle.
There is part of code (interceptor) where I check if user is authenticated:

```
 intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any> | any> {

    return next.handle(this.addTokenToRequest(request, this.authService.getToken()))
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
        if (err.status === 0 || err.status === 401) {
            // if server return 401 Unauthorized
            this.authService.logout();
            location.reload(true);
        } else if (err.status === 302) {
          this.router.navigate(['/pages/technical-works']);
        } else {
              return throwError(err.error);
            }
          }));

      private addTokenToRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string): HttpRequest<any> {
           return request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } 
                               });
      }
}
```

So If server return unauthorized error then i logout in client side.

Comment: It's a good solution to log out when authorization is not valid anymore and it works. But this won't work for pages that don't request or have cached pages.

Comment: If you want a server to send request about customer to client then look something like SignalR (I use it in c#).

Comment: Thanks for that great idea of SignalR. Helps to know something like that exists. I just can't integrate it right now in my project and I solved it differently. But I did find an alternative for Symfony: https://symfony.com/blog/symfony-gets-real-time-push-capabilities

Comment: I will accept your answer since I think it's the better solution. Mainly the SignalR part.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my solution was that my authentication works with a behavior subject. For that reason it didn't work like I wanted when I changed it in the canActivate. However I managed to solve this (in combination with the interceptor solution of @Roma Ruzich) by checking if the authorization is still valid. If not, log out.

```
  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    this.authService.getAuthStatus().subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (!data.deviceRegistered) {
        this.authService.logout();
      }
    });
    return this.authService.getIsAuthenticated();
  }
```